# Parse NSInternalInconsistencyException raises with PFImageView

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfimageview

I'm experiencing an odd behaviour of Parse right now. 
My App worked fine for weeks of development and never raised a 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' since project setup. 
But I just implemented a PFImageView in my ProfileViewController (second VC in UITabBarController, therefore only showing when user is logged in) and my App keeps crashing with this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You have to call setApplicationId:clientKey: on Parse to configure Parse.'
```

Of course I checked my Parse setup in `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool`:

```
    Parse.setApplicationId("myApplicationID", clientKey: "myClientKey")

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    // This is where I used to activate Parse, but SO and Parse forums kept
    // saying you should try to do this at the very beginning

    ParseCrashReporting.enable()

    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptionsInBackground(launchOptions, block: nil)
```

In my ProfileViewController this is where I load my image from Parse:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    userImageView.file = user["profilePicture"] as PFFile

    userImageView.loadInBackground { (image, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            JSSAlertView().danger(self, title: "Loading Image Failed", text: "Please check your connection")
        } else {

            self.userImageView.image = image
        }
    }

}
```

Setting the instance variable of image:

```
var image: UIImage? {

    // If User picked a new image, automatically update imageView
    didSet {

        userImageView.image = image

        // Convert image to PNG and save in in Parse-Cloud
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        let imageFile = PFFile(name: "profilePicture.png", data: imageData)

        // Attach this file to our user
        user["profilePicture"] = imageFile

        user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {

                JSSAlertView().danger(self, title: "Failed To Save Image", text: "Please try again saving your image!")
            }
        }


        userImageView.file = user["profilePicture"] as PFFile
    }

}
```

I have no clue what kind of connection could be between these things, but I didn't change anything else in the whole project.

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried loading your image in your viewdidload instead...?

Comment: Yes I did, same outcome as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally after hours of trial and error I found the solution for this problem. 
You should **never ever execute parse calls in the header of view controllers**, as these calls could be executed before the API registration.

For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  // this will crash the app as above!
  var user: PFUser! = PFUser.currentUser()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      // initialize the user here. This will work just fine
      user = PFUser.currentUser()
  }
}
```

Hope this saves you from having the same errors!

Comment: hey i have a question regarding JSSAlertView, how are you getting the alerts to show in your `if else` statements without `presentViewContoller` method? are you initializing them or?